# Postgresql - index on individual array elements or index on keys in an hstore

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing, hstore

I have a table of users, with a column uuid and a column tags:

`| uuid varchar PRIMARY KEY | tags ????? |`

I am not sure what type the column `tags` should be, hstore or varchar[]. I want it to contain a list of interests or categories, like 'burgers' or 'vegetables', such that I can query for all users who have any tags in a specified array (i.e. "Which users like any of 'burgers' 'vegetables' 'hotdogs'?") For this query to be fast, I imagine I should *index on the individual categories* however they are stored. I expect most users to have a small number of tags (0-5) but they could potentially have up to 100 or so. And there are many different options of tags (could be 1000+).

I believe I can index on *keys in an hstore* so that I know hstore type is an option. Is it possible to index on *individual varchar elements of arrays*? (I've seen posts about this but they were inconclusive.)

---

Postgres version 9.3.5

Comment: Have you really thought through the option of using a separate table for tags? I've implemented tags in a corporate production environment and would strongly recommend using a separate table or tables. For example one table with user-tag-mappings and a possibly a separate table for tags (that gives each tag name an id) if you need to be sure you can group by a tag name.

Usually in a database environment these kind of array solutions a best implemented in separate tables.

Comment: I had not thought that through! Can you explain that (or link)? It sounds like a solid recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend separate tables for tags

You already have Table users with uuid, let's say:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    uuid serial primary key,
    user_name text
);
```

Now the tags:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    tag_id serial primary key,
    tag_name text
);

CREATE TABLE users_tags (
    uuid integer references users,
    tag_id integer references tags,
    primary key (uuid, tag_id)
);
```

Now you can easily query with for example:

```
SELECT * FROM users
    JOIN users_tags USING (uuid)
    JOIN tags USING (tag_id)
    WHERE tag_name = 'Burgers';
```

Now you can easily add index on tag_name. You can also easily force uniqueness on tag name or create a unique index on lower(tag_name) that would eliminate problems with capital letters in tag names (Burgers vs. BurgerS).

A simpler solution would be to leave the tag table out and just create:

```
CREATE TABLE users_tags (
    uuid integer references users,
    tag_name text,
    primary key (uuid, tag_name)
);
```

Whether you create a separate table for tags or just use users_tags -table mostly depends on how tags are used. Separate table is needed if you have a (mostly) defined set of tags and you maybe want to add info to a specific tag name later. The query "which users like 'hotdogs'" would suggest a separate tagle where tag 'hotdog' has a specific ID. If users can freely add all kinds of mumbojumbo tags and no info will be attached to them later then leave the separate table out.

Comment: Awesome! My use case makes sense for that last one, using only the users_tags table. Could that `primary key` be `(uuid, tag_name)` instead of `(uuid, tag_id)`?

Comment: And last thing (I think), if I want to find all uuids that are associated with a tag like 'vegetables', I can basically do a simple `"SELECT uuid FROM users INNER JOIN users_tags USING uuid ON users.uuid = users_tags.uuid WHERE users_tags.tag_name = 'vegetables'"` but to make this very fast, what index would I need to add? A regular one (`'btree'`) on `users_tags(tag_name)`?

Comment: And would I also want one on `users_tags(uuid)`?

Comment: I think creating the primary key would create a two-part unique index that would be used on your particular query (you could check this by putting explain in front of select) but a btree index on tag_name would probably be needed too for other uses.